# Jinja 2 - displaying all my words instead of one

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Please excuse my code, I am still a relative beginner trying to complete a school project! Basically, I am trying to create a language learning system where you input a word and it checks if it is correct. However, on the page [learn.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWfse.png) all of the words in my database are coming up. I want to get it so that when you load the page there is the first word and when you click the button it checks that word, allowing the page to display the next word to translate. An example of this would be [memrise](https://app.memrise.com/home/), this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1nO9.png) shows the kind of system that I am trying to emulate.

I know that this is because of the for loop but I have tried lots of solutions to no success. It seems like a really easy problem but I am really stuck. I have 0 JavaScript expertise so if possible I would try to stay away from JS solutions. I will really appreciate any help possible :)

learn.html

```
  {% block content %}
    

    <form class = "form" id="form1" action="/learn/check" methods=["POST"]>
      <td>
        
        <h5> Please enter the spanish for : {% for word in course_content %}{{ word.english }}  {% endfor %} </h5>
      
        <input type="text" name="language_learning_input" id="desc" value="" size="100" maxlength="140"/>
        <p> </p>

      </td>
      <input type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Update"/>
    </form>
  {% endblock content %}
```

snippet of main.py

```
#LEARN SYSTEM

#STORING DB VALUES IN LISTS
def spanish():
  #setting variables
  holding_spanish = []

  #running db query
  course_content = db.session.query(Course).all()

  #iterating through db
  for row in course_content:
    holding_spanish.append(row.spanish)
  
  return holding_spanish

def english():
  #setting variables
  holding_english = []

  #running db query
  course_content = db.session.query(Course).all()

  #iterating through db
  for row in course_content:
    holding_english.append(row.english)
  
  return holding_english

def score():
  #setting variables
  holding_score = []

  #running db query
  account_settings = db.session.query(AccountSettings).all()

  #iterating through db
  for row in account_settings:
    holding_score.append(row.words_per_lesson)
  
  return holding_score

#MAIN LEARN PAGE
@app.route("/learn")
def learn():
  #getting values
  english()
  spanish()
  score()
  x=1
  testingvalue = [score()]
  acccount_settings = db.session.query(AccountSettings).all()
  course_content = db.session.query(Course).all()
  return render_template('learn.html', course_content=course_content, acccount_settings=acccount_settings,testingvalue=testingvalue,x=x,english=english)

#ROUTE USED TO CHECK
@app.route("/learn/check", methods =['GET'])
def learncheck():
  course_content = db.session.query(Course).all()
  language_learning_input = request.args.get('language_learning_input')

  for row in course_content:
    if language_learning_input == row.spanish:
      "<h1> correcto! </h1>"
      print("true")
    else:
      "<h1> not correcto! :</h1>"
      print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to understand two things.

First, of the many words you have to return only one. *

So, how do you know which word the user has already seen?

You don't. HTTP is a stateless protocoll. That means, each request (access by a browser) is independent of another one.

But you can work around this limitation.

So, second, you need to save the state. And there are several concepts.

From the top of my head, you could use

- sessions
- cookies
- or pass a parameter with e.h. the current word, so you can deduct the next word

That's it. Enjoy your homework and do not hesitate to create a new question when you encounter a specific problem

- You could also return all words, and then do the cycling through the words via Javascript.